# Is it possible to pass a method as an argument in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, method-signature

I have a method that varies by a single method call inside, and I'd like to pass the method/signature of the method that it varies by as an argument... is this possible in Objective C or is that too much to hope for?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

NSInvocation is a class for wrapping up a method calls in an object.  You can set a selector (method signature), set arguments by index. You can then set a target and call invoke to trigger the call, or leave the target unset and use invokeWithTarget: in a loop of some sort to call this on many objects.

I think it works a little like this:

```
NSInvocation *inv = [[NSInvocation alloc] init];
[inv setSelector:@selector(foo:bar:)];
[inv setArgument:123 atIndex:0];
[inv setArgument:456 atIndex:1];

for (MyClass *myObj in myObjects) {
  [inv invokeWithTarget:myObj];
}
```

Or if you dont want to pass invocation objects into this method you can use the SEL type to accept a selector (method signature).

```
-(void)fooWithMethod:(SEL)selector;
```

*Then* assign the selector to an invocation object in order to call it on objects.

Comment: I just tried this and was unable to get it to work without first setting a method signature like this:

`NSMethodSignature* sig = [self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(foo:bar:)];`
`NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];`

From there it should work.

Comment: Also, be sure to start argument index at 2: `Indices 0 and 1 indicate the hidden arguments self and _cmd, respectively; you should set these values directly with the target and selector properties. Use indices 2 and greater for the arguments normally passed in a message.` - [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSInvocation/setArgument:atIndex:)

Answer (score 10):

Or if you're using the `fooWithMethod:(SEL)selector` approach, just do `[myObject performSelector:selector]` on it, if it has no other arguments.

See [NSObject for details](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

As said before you can pass the selector of the method you want to call. Using a selector there are different ways to actually call the method:

1. using `NSObject`s  `performSelector:`, `performSelector:withObject:` and `performSelector:withObject:withObject:` methods
2. using a `NSInvocation` object
3. or directly using `objc_msgSend` or `objc_msgSend_stret`
4. using the `IMP` of that method which you can get using `methodForSelector:`

Which one to use really depends on the situation. If the performance is not critical I’d go ahead with 1 if you need to pass in 0, 1 or 2 objects. If the `performSelector:...` methods don’t match I’d go with 2 or 3. Since setting up an `NSInvocation` object requires a lot of boilerplate code I prefer 3, but I guess that’s a matter of personal choice, unless there are performance issues.

If the performance of those method calls does matter I’d use 3 or 4. 3 should be faster unless you can cache the `IMP`s. But depending on your code this may not be feasible or doesn’t really help. So here you must profile the code and see which one is better for you.