# How to I pass @selector as a parameter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, selector

For the method:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(method:) toTarget:self withObject:(id)SELECTOR];
```

How do I pass in a @selector? I tried casting it to (id) to make it compile, but it crashes in runtime.

---

More specifically, I have a method like this:

```
+(void)method1:(SEL)selector{
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(method2:) toTarget:self withObject:selector];   
}
```

It crashes. How do I pass in the selector without crashing, so that the new thread can call the selector when the thread is ready?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The problem here isn't passing a selector to a method, per se, but passing a selector where an object is expected. To pass a non-object value as an object, you can use [`NSValue`](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html). In this case, you'll need to create a method that accepts an NSValue and retrieves the appropriate selector. Here's an example implementation:

```
@implementation Thing
- (void)method:(SEL)selector {
    // Do something
}

- (void)methodWithSelectorValue:(NSValue *)value {
    SEL selector;

    // Guard against buffer overflow
    if (strcmp([value objCType], @encode(SEL)) == 0) {
        [value getValue:&selector];
        [self method:selector];
    }
}

- (void)otherMethodShownInYourExample {
    SEL selector = @selector(something);
    NSValue *selectorAsValue = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&selector objCType:@encode(SEL)];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(methodWithSelectorValue:) toTarget:self withObject:selectorAsValue];
}
@end
```

Comment: @cstack: If you look at the question, spawning a new thread is what he OP was trying to do. So I used the same task in my example. But this technique isn't in any way specific to spawning a new thread.

Answer (score 43):

You can convert between selectors and string objects using the `NSStringFromSelector()` and `NSSelectorFromString()` functions. So you can just pass string objects instead.

Alternately, if you don't want to change your methods, you can create an `NSInvocation` to create an invocation for your method call (since it can set up invocations with non-object arguments), and then to call it do `[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(invoke) toTarget:myInvocation withObject:nil];`

Comment: This is the best answer of the lot, wish i could get more people to upvote this one.

Comment: the is the easier approach - it should be the chosen answer in my opinion

Answer (score 4):

Use NSValue, like so:

```
+(void)method1:(SEL)selector {
    NSValue *selectorValue = [NSValue value:&selector withObjCType:@encode(SEL)];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(method2:) 
                             toTarget:self 
                           withObject:selectorValue];
}
```

NSValue is intended as an object-wrapper for arbitrary non-object types.

Comment: I believe you are missing an "&" sign before "selector" so that it ends up being "... value:&selector ..." instead of "... value:selector ...".

Answer (score 2):

Please see: [passing a method as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519600/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-method-as-an-argument-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to specify an object just use nil.

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(method:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

If you need to pass an object to the selector it would look something like this.

Here I'm passing a string to the method "setText".

```
NSString *string = @"hello world!";
 [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(setText:) toTarget:self withObject:string];


-(void)setText:(NSString *)string {
    [UITextField setText:string]; 
}
```