# How can I add arguments to a selector passed as a parameter in ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, selector

I'm trying to write a method in Objective C which takes a @selector as a parameter.  It works fine - provided that I don't want the selector itself to have parameters (and I do).

```
- (void) testWithInput:(NSString*) testString1 andInput:(NSString*)testString2 {
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", testString1, testString2);
}

- (void)executeSelector:(SEL)func fromObject:(id)object {
    [object performSelector:func];
}

- (void)runSelector {
    NSString* string1 = @"Hello ";
    NSString* string2 = @"World";
    [self executeSelector:@selector(testWithInput:andInput:) fromObject:self];
}
```

But how, in the runSelector function can I specify that string1 and string2 need to be passed in as arguments for the selector?

I suppose that I could pass in the parameters as a separate set of arguments to execute selector - but that feels quite messy.  Is there a neater way?

I've done a bit of research, on StackOverflow (and elsewhere) - but either the answer isn't quite right or I can't understand it fully.

[How to I pass @selector as a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932801/how-to-i-pass-selector-as-a-parameter)

[How can I pass a parameter to a selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372468/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-selector)

[Objective-C: Calling selectors with multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018195/objective-c-calling-selectors-with-multiple-arguments)

In fact, I'm comfortable passing parameters to selectors normally - it's when the selector is itself a parameter that I have a problem.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're trying to do. Do you want to pass the selector and the two strings in one argument? Is a block parameter what you're looking for? Or `NSInvocation`? Or a `userInfo` argument like in the `NSTimer` methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add parameters for the arguments. Your contrived example will work with the following changes:

```
- (void) testWithInput:(NSString*) testString1 andInput:(NSString*)testString2 {
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", testString1, testString2);
}

- (void)executeSelector:(SEL)func fromObject:(id)object withString1:(NSString *)string1 andString2:(NSString *)string2 {
    // This doesn't scale. Two arguments is as far as you can go using `performSelector`.
    [object performSelector:func withObject:string1 withObject:string2];
}

- (void)runSelector {
    NSString* string1 = @"Hello ";
    NSString* string2 = @"World";
    [self executeSelector:@selector(testWithInput:andInput:) fromObject:self withString1:string1 andString2:string2];
}
```

Since it's unclear what you are actually trying to accomplish it is difficult to offer any further advice on a better solution other than to suggest using blocks is likely a better choice.

Comment: I feared that might be the solution.  Maybe blocks would be the better solution - guess I'd better learn how to do that!