# Objective-C passing methods as parameters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, selector

How do you pass one method as a parameter to another method? I'm doing this across classes.

Class A:

```
+ (void)theBigFunction:(?)func{
    // run the func here
}
```

Class B:

```
- (void)littleBFunction {
    NSLog(@"classB little function");
}

// somewhere else in the class
[ClassA theBigFunction:littleBFunction]
```

Class C:

```
- (void)littleCFunction {
    NSLog(@"classC little function");
}

// somewhere else in the class
[ClassA theBigFunction:littleCFunction]
```

Comment: You pass selectors, Here is a similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519600/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-method-as-an-argument-in-objective-c

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The type you are looking for is selector (`SEL`) and you get a method's selector like this:

```
SEL littleSelector = @selector(littleMethod);
```

If the method takes parameters, you just put `:` where they go, like this:

```
SEL littleSelector = @selector(littleMethodWithSomething:andSomethingElse:);
```

Also, methods are not really functions, they are used to send messages to specific class (when starting with +) or specific instance of it (when starting with -). Functions are C-type that doesn't really have a "target" like methods do.

Once you get a selector, you call that method on your target (be it class or instance) like this:

```
[target performSelector:someSelector];
```

A good example of this is `UIControl`'s [addTarget:action:forControlEvents:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget%3aaction%3aforControlEvents%3a) method you usually use when creating `UIButton` or some other control objects programmatically.

Comment: You know how I would call the function once it is passed in? I *doubt* [self func] will work.

Comment: [target performSelector:someSelector];

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to look at blocks.  It allows you to pass a block of code (a closure) around.

Here's a good write up on blocks:

http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/7/28/ios4-blocks-1

Here's the apple docs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html

Comment: This should be accepted answer, as it is much more versatile. It also simplifies the case where passing arguments to the called method is dependent on context.

Answer (score 7):

Objective C makes this operation relatively easy.  Apple provides [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocSelectors.html%22following%20documentation%22).

To directly address your question, you are not calling a function, but a selector.  Here is some sample code:

Big Function:

```
+ (void)theBigFunction:(SEL)func fromObject:(id) object{
    [object preformSelector:func]
}
```

Then for class B:

```
- (void)littleBFunction {
    NSLog(@"classB little function");
}

// somewhere else in the class
[ClassA theBigFunction:@selector(littleBFunction) fromObject:self]
```

Then for class C:

```
- (void)littleCFunction {
    NSLog(@"classC little function");
}

// somewhere else in the class
[ClassA theBigFunction:@selector(littleCFunction) fromObject:self]
```

EDIT: Fix selectors sent (remove the semicolon)

Comment: Your selectors don't match method descriptions, there shouldn't be any `:` at the end of them.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that.  I'm not much of an objective c coder (I've only dabbled in it) and I followed Apple's examples too closely!

Answer (score 5):

You can use Blocks for this purpose. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html